# Open tcp InetSocketAddress to application path (not just host + port)

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm attempting to connect to a TCP socket in Android.

I know the socket service works because I can connect and interact with it in a browser (in JavaScript) as follows:

```
var ws = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;  
window.ws = new wsImpl('ws://foo.bar.com:8282/MySocketService', 'my-protocol');  
...
```

---

So, in my Android app:

This connects successfully, but I never receive messages from it:

```
SocketAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress("foo.bar.com", 8282);
```

This fails to connect:

```
SocketAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress("foo.bar.com/MySocketService", 8282);
```

and I receive an error like:

> *java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: foo.bar.com/MySocketService:8282*

Is there any way to indicate the application path for a TCP service?

Comment: Are you using a proxy server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP end-point is just IP address and a port number. What you are talking about is handled by upper-level protocols on top of TCP, like HTTP, so you need to look at other utilities like [`java.net.URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).

Comment: Ok. It appears I will need to host service at dedicated host name.